# ionic 2 - Typescript module not found error

Tags: typescript, ionic2, angular2-template

I run below command:

```
ionic cordova run
```

which gives me below error

```
? What platform would you like to run: ios, android: android
Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
```

Below is :

```
ionic info
```

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1 
Gulp CLI    : CLI version 1.2.2 Local version 3.9.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
Node              : v8.4.0
npm               : 5.2.0 
OS                : Linux 3.13
```

I searched lots of places but I didn't get a solution for this. Please help.

Comment: are you make npm install , also trying to make 
typescript install

Comment: Yes tried by deleting node_modules folder and run npm install and npm install typescript too but not worked.

Comment: try this to install typingscript \n
"npm install -g tsd"

Comment: Tried this too now, but not working. My node version is 8.4.0 and npm version is 5.2.0
. May this create problem?

Comment: trying to make new ionic project from beginning and  see if error still happen

Comment: Thank you very much Bassam! It works finally by re-creating the application.